# Changing order of R Facets without changing orientation of plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am trying to reorder violin plots using facet_grid. Everything is good using this code, except the vertical order of the plots aren't what I want them to be:

```html
ggplot(data = LTheartbeats, aes(x= factor(Condition), y = Heartbeats, fill = factor(Condition))) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = .1) +
  geom_violin(alpha = .75, trim = FALSE) +
  ylim(0,40)+
  facet_grid(Timepoint~ .,) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Treatment") + 
  labs(x = "\n Timepoint (Hours Post Exposure)", y = "Heartbeats (Per 10 Seconds) \n", 
       title = " \n") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=20,face="bold"), 
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=15), 
        axis.text = element_text(size= 8),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="black", size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", colour="black", size = 20))
```

To fix it, I've added this line of code, which successfully changes the order of the plots, but also flips the orientation of the different plots to be horizontal instead of vertical:

```html
   facet_grid(~factor(Timepoint, levels = c("2hr", "8hr", "12hr", "18hr", "24hr"))) +**
```

Images of what the code results in:
Correct orientation:
[image]

Wrong orientation:
[image]

How do I keep the same orientation as in the first image, but still change the vertical order of the plots? Thanks!

Comment: From the `facet_grid` reference: "For compatibility with the classic interface, rows can also be a formula with the rows (of the tabular display) on the LHS and the columns (of the tabular display) on the RHS; the dot in the formula is used to indicate there should be no faceting on this dimension (either row or column)."
Then use `facet_grid( factor(Time_point***) ~ . )`

Comment: Using a combination of that, and the previous code worked, thank you so much! 
  facet_grid(~factor(Timepoint, levels = c("2hr", "8hr", "12hr", "18hr", "24hr")) ~ .) +